# How to receive the email via route of mailgun?

Tags: php, email, mailgun

I am new in mailgun.

I just create mailgun account.  And verified new DNS.

```
SMTP Hostname
smtp.mailgun.org
Default SMTP Login
postmaster@example.com
Default Password
e1dfdse34343wewe3232323232323wewewewe
API Base URL
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/example.com
API Key
key-53234545453trter334233e
```

Of course current some value is dummy value.  And I create new route.

Recipient : `demo@example.com`

Of course I set actions. Like this:   `https://example.com/message`

I thought when I send the email via mailgun, then any user can reply with this email.

`demo@example.com`

But I cannot send the reply email.    In a nutshell I can send email, but cannot accept any email.

Not sure am I wrong.

I searched lots of methods, but all are speaking enable.

Not sure what am I missing.

Please let me know if you  know on this.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you said an email to demo@example.com? What are your route settings?

Comment: Yes.  It says wrong email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this myself.  This was simple issue.   I set the MXA priority as 10. So it arouse the google.    That is why I cannot receive any Email.    I hope anyone will not meet this problems if he read this.  Thanks.